# The count function is not counting certain cells, it brings it up as zero vba

Tags: excel, vba

The count function is not working as intended. It brings up the selected count as 0, even though there is data in those cells. I tried with different cells and it works for some but not others - some of the cells have drop down information, but not all.

```
Sub AssignCount()
   Dim result As Integer
'Assign the variable
   result = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("C11:C18"))
'Show the result
   MsgBox "The number of cells populated with values is " & result
   
End Sub
```

Comment: `Count()` would only count numbers. Are you sure there is actual numbers in that range? Also, your current `Range()` object is implicitly refering to the then active worksheet. Be sure to refer to the appropriate worksheet using explicit referencing too.

Comment: What are you counting? text or numbers??

Comment: @JvdV whats the best way to make it specific ? I was going to put something like the following, but this gets the result of 0: 
'''
'Assign the variable
   result = WorksheetFunction.CountA(resourcing.Range("b2000").End(xlUp).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)))
'Show the result
   MsgBox "The number of cells populated with values is " & result
'''

Comment: @JvdV
but with the above code, it now goes back to 0 count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to be explicit about your range object. Also, depending on what you want to count, try to switch to `COUNTA()` function to count numeric & string values:

```
Sub AssignCount()
    Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("resourcing")
    Dim lr As Long, result As Long: lr = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = sht.Range("B2:B" & lr)
    
    result = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)
    MsgBox "The number of cells populated with values is " & result
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: In your comments you refer to column B whereas in your Q it was column C. I went with the former. Also note that if all cells are always filled untill the last found row you can just simply use the `lr` variable and avoid the worksheetfunction alltogether.

Comment: If you could help me understand the above please.
you put in `lr` and set it as `sht` (which is the worksheet it is doing it on), then put `cells(sht.` but sht is there again? followed by the `rows.count.2` which to my little knowledge means it goes to column 2 and finds all the data with a value correct? which is not entirely what i need. I wanted it to go to the worksheet, and start at say B2000 and end(xlUP) so that it may find the last inputted data from my other macro, and select that data to count. if that makes any sense :)

Comment: i wanted to fully understand so that I may use in the future and be able to adapt it how I need. really appreciate the help by the way <3
If you give a man a fish, you feed him for a day. If you teach a man to fish, you feed him for a lifetime

Comment: @user20109552 given the comments in the answer, like "be explicit about your range object" etc then it looks like JvdV **is** teaching you to fish. But as the saying goes "you can lead a horse to water, but you cannot make it drink"...

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for your wisdom, though the comment doesn't help. I was ultimately trying to understand the code he wrote, so yes, exactly as you say to make it more 'explicit' and to change it how I need.. but that's exactly where the problem is... I've never coded before, so getting my head around things isn't simple.

Comment: @user20109552 I'm not behind a pc more to edit accordingly now. The gist of it is that we Set the worksheet we will refer to with the sht variable. Then we indeed get the lr variable when checking column B and get the row with the last value in that column.

Comment: @JvdV after some trial and error I got to understand it though took some time, but it was great help!! thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

**Count** : Only count the numeric values

It's better to use **CountA** instead which works for both number & categorical data